Cyclicity of k digits in Powers of 3
To show : The last k digits of ${3}^a$ and $3^{a +4×5^{k-1}}$ are same.
$$OR$$
${3}^a$mod(${10}^k$) = $3^{a +4×5^{k-1}}$ mod(${10}^k$)
It can be true or false I don't know.
I was solving another math problem related to perimeter of a triangle
Question
while solving the question I observed the above pattern .
3 to the power 4 and 24
3 to the power 0 and 20 have same last two digit.pattern
after it I assumed it to be true and solved the question and got the desired answer I tried to prove the pattern but I wasn't able to .
actually I am quite new to number theory and actually only know some defination and a bit of property of $mod$  if any one can help or even give hints It would be very helpful.

Please edit to include your efforts.  A natural start might be to show this for small $k$.

I know that it works for k=1 due to cyclicity but don't know how to formally write it and how to go about proving for other case .

Well, a similar argument will work with somewhat more effort.  For each $k$, you'll want to compute the Carmichael Function, $\lambda (10^k)$.  You don't need cyclicity.

False. $,3^{\large 4\cdot 5^{k-1}}!!\color{#c00}{\equiv 1}\pmod{!10^k},$ fails first at $,k!=!5,$ by $,3^{\large 4\cdot 5^4}!!\equiv 17\color{#c00}{\not\equiv 1}\pmod{!2^5}.$ However, it does hold true mod $5^k$ (vs. $10^k$) by Euler's totient theorem. $\ \ $

More generally you can use LTE = Lifting the Exponent to calculate the exact power of $2$ and $5$ dividing $,a^n-1,$ or $,a^n-b^n.,$ You can find many examples in prior posts here. $\ \ $

Thank you for pointing Euler's totient theorem. After I searched it , it becam more clear why there was 4×$5^{k-1}$ in the exponent it was φ(${5}^k$) and that's why it was congruent mod $5^{k}$ and . It was actually Euler's totient theorem but just for 3 and congurent mod ${5}^k$ and that's why it will always work for mod ${5}^k$ and just happened to work for mod ${2}^k$ for k<5.
